# How to debug react-native-web with Expo and vscode?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-web, react-native-debugger, react-native-tools

I am trying to find how react-native-web apps (specifically using Expo and  vscode) can be debugged.

I found guidance neither in the web, nor in the `react-native-web`'s own site.

The debug configuration that comes with the [React Native Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native) aims to run within the Expo application, but my intention is to use the browser to debug/test the react-native-web behaviour.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug in Exponent",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "platform": "exponent",
            "expoHostType": "local"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I could have found the method. For all who are stuck the method is as follows.

1. Go to the debug pane.

   [image]
2. If previously not chosen choose "Run and Debug"

   [image]
3. Choose add configuration.

   [image]
4. Choose Chrome: Launch (we would like to launch a chrome browser when we start debugging, you may have alternative browsers, or you may choose to have the attach approach also). (We will come back to here after step 5.)

   [image]

It will add a configuration like:

```json
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080", // This line should be modified at step 6
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
```

5. Open the vscode's terminal and run `expo start --web` and you should see your server and related port. (Below, in my case it is port 19006.)

[image]

6. Modify the configuration.

```json
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome 19006", // Modified as 19006
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:19006", // Modified as 19006
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
```

7. Confirm that `expo start --web` is running then go to the debug pane and launch a browser by the debug start button, with "Launch Chrome 19006" value:

[image]

After these 6 steps you should be able to debug Expo applications that use `react-native-web` through the vscode.